# J2t_Ajaxcheckout installation

Tags: magento

Question has to do with the well known to the magento community, **J2T Ajax cart**, which can be found [here](http://www.j2t-design.net/index.php/magento-extensions/surf-experience-enhancements/j2t-ajax-cart.html).

Although the installation seems straightforward, you are assumed to copy the files to appropriate directories and modify from the administrator panel. After a "successful" installation cart's behaviour remains the same. I used the term "successful" since the JavaScript files are loading along with the css.

Are there any additional steps missing from the installation procedure?
(note: development magento's version is *1.4.0.1*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin extructure

- frontend/default/default/images/j2t
- frontend/default/default/css/j2t
- frontend/default/default/layout/j2tajaxcheckout.xml
- frontend/default/default/template/j2tajaxcheckout

comented all **j2tajaxcheckout.xml** and add to **catalog.xml**

```
<default>         
 <reference name="before_body_end">
   <block type="core/template" name="j2t_ajax_wrapper" after="-" template="j2tajaxcheckout/ajax_wrapper.phtml" />
 </reference>
</default>
```

and final file **catalog.xml**

```
<!--
AJAX cart modulo
-->

   <j2tajaxcheckout_index_cart>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
          <remove name="head"/>
            <remove name="header"/>
            <remove name="footer"/>
            <remove name="left"/>
            <remove name="right"/>
            <remove name="before_body_end"/>

            <block type="j2tajaxcheckout/cart" name="j2tajaxcheckout" template="j2tajaxcheckout/ajaxcart.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_ajax" as="cart_sidebar_ajax" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference> 
    </j2tajaxcheckout_index_cart>
```

Comment: Also for purpose of completeness, the js files for this extension should be placed in the js folder of the installation.